# How to set the min property of one date field deriving from another date field

Tags: javascript

I am writing a JS application where I have two date fields. One to select the "from" date and the other to select the "to" date.

I need to set the minimum of "to" date to the value of "from" date. The below is my code:

```
datePickerFromId.min = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
datePickerToId.min = datePickerFromId;
```

But this does not work at all. Even the minimum of "from" date is not set to the value of current date. How to solve this issue?

Comment: why did you set the locale as en-gb? is there any specific reason?

Comment: just to show the date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: When you say _"date field"_, do you mean `<input type="date">`?

Comment: @Phil yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the comment `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB')` will show the date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format while the min expects date to be in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` [according](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#max) to MDN.

You can use the below to correctly give min value

`datePickerFromId.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];`

To help you in your case to reflect the date change use the below code:

```
datePickerFromId.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
datePickerToId.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];

datePickerFromId.onchange = function(dateEvent){
  datePickerToId.value="";
  var fromDate = datePickerFromId.value;
  datePickerToId.min = new Date(fromDate).toISOString().split("T")[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it must be in the ISO format is it?

Comment: Yes, according to the link I mentioned previously. To know about ISO format in date time visit here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 .